# libharu HPDF_Page_TextRect utf8 character line break inside word

Tags: c++, utf-8, libharu

I just recognized a weird issue within the libharu c++ pdf-library (osx 10.6). Hope someone can give me a clue how to solve this.

I am using a HPDF_Page_TextRect() to write auto-break supported text(utf8). Now it seams like libharu interprets special characters the same as spaces and separates words if they appear at the end of a line.